# javascript rearrange array index based on value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that look like this

```
var array = [{id:5},{id:1},{id:2}]
```

I want to rearrange the array index based on the id value from lowest to highest so it becomes

```
var newarray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:5}]
```

I have been looking at sort() but I dont quite understand the logic behind it.

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)`

Comment: [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) explains it pretty well.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yup, the only difference being that instead of returning a - b, since the array contains objects you would return a.id - b.id

Comment: @RohanRao I never said the documentation gave an exact solution; I said it explained the `sort` function. They OP can apply it to their needs

Comment: @choz make an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use native array [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function which you can pass a callback as a compare function.

```js
var array = [{id:5},{id:1},{id:2}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(array); //[{"id": 1 }, {"id": 2 }, {"id": 5 } ]
```